# sending serialized int32_t in a char buffer and parse it back to int32_t

Tags: c, printf, int32

I want to send a structure from a client to a Server via udp. Therefor I want to write a int32_t (because of the fixed size, so I know where to find it in the char[]).

When I use (Counter, total and size are int32_t)

```
snprintf(*netbuf, headersize , "%d:%d:%d:%s:", np->total, np->counter, np->size, np->filename);
```

and try to read it back like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{   
      tmp[0][i] = netbuf[t];
}
np->total = (int32_t) atoi(tmp[0]);
```

the value is always 0 so there is something wrong. Is there any Chance I can print an int32_t to a buffer?

Comment: As Babbage would say, "I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question." But seriously: the fixed-lenghtness of fixed length types can be exploited for your purposes if you serialize straight in binary, not in text. If you serialize an `int32_t` as text it will be just as variable-length as a plain `int`. Besides, that `sprintf` is wrong - if `int32_t` does not coincide with `int` or with a smaller type you get undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you, maybe I should try to save the int as binary digit first and print that binary to the buffer

Comment: You don't "print" binary data, if you use `sprintf`-family functions to print strings they'll just truncate at the first NUL - and in binary data there'll be plenty. You have to compose your buffer with `memcpy` and the like. TBH, I fear that you have really confused ideas about what is usually meant as binary data - you may be better off just serializing your data as text as you are already doing, but making it fixed-width with the appropriate formatting specifiers.

Comment: thx for your help, I found a workin way to do what I wanted with memcpy  :)